# xpages download control fails on certain attachments

Tags: xpages

I have a download control bound to a rich text field.  My users are finding that some documents cause errors.  Right now, I have an XPage that has little more than the rich text field on it.  For example, when I attach a certain .docx file to a document using the Notes client, then try to download the attachment via the Web using the download control on an xpage, I get a runtime error stating that there is an invalid date.  I actually get the error just by trying to open the XPage, before I even get a chance to click on the link within the download control.  But neither the xpage nor the attachment have any date field on them.  Other attachments don't cause the error, even other .docx documents.  And if I convert the .docx to .doc, the problem goes away.  But I can't tell my users to never attach .docx documents.  Does anyone have any idea why some .docx (not all, though) documents attached to a Notes document would cause such a runtime error in XPages?

Comment: Does this happen when you attach the docx via the browser, too? Did you set the rtf in your form to store the content as MIME?

Comment: Awww, that was too easy!  Thanks Oliver for pointing me to something I should have already checked.  That appears to have taken care of the issue.